# The difference between a boundary and boundaries

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I am wondering what's the difference between a boundary and boundaries?

As I can guess, **the boundary** is, for example, an edge of some sort of figure:

[image: one edge of a rectangle selected]

But **the boundaries** is the all boundaries:

[image: all edges of a rectangle selected]

Another example. **The boundary** is the boundary between Canada and USA, but **the USA boundaries** includes the boundary between USA and Canada and the boundary between USA and Mexico.

Am I right?

Comment: Obviously you're right (*boundary* is singular, and *boundaries* is plural). Is there a meaningful question here?

Comment: In some figurative contexts, such as *He overstepped the **boundary / boundaries / bounds** of civilised conversation*, it doesn't really make any difference whether you use singular ***boundary*** or plural ***boundaries***. But note that for my *specific* example, plural ***bounds*** is in fact far more common anyway (and singular ***bound*** rarely if ever occurs in such contexts).

Comment: For example, a man write: prove that the boundary of a rectangle in Rn has measure zero (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773390/prove-that-the-boundary-of-a-rectangle-in-mathbbrn-has-measure-zero). He means by "boundary" all edges of a rectangle.

Comment: Another example: "We know perimeter of a rectangle is the total length (distance) of the boundary of a rectangle" (https://www.math-only-math.com/perimeter-of-a-rectangle.html).

Comment: So it looks that I am wrong in my assumption.

Comment: The precise meaning of "boundary" depends on context. I'd say that a "closed" geometric shape (any polygon, for example, including squares and circles) has only ***one*** boundary - that which separates the ***inside*** from the ***outside***. At that level, it's like ***perimeter*** (a closed 2-d shape only has one perimeter). But at the level of ***geography***, I'd often think of a ***country*** as having as many boundaries as there are adjoining countries (perhaps plus one for a shoreline). At the country level, ***boundary*** is like ***border***.

Comment: Thank you. But it's pretty complicated to feel this context for non-native language speakers.